# What is the next number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

What is the next number in the following set ?

$$1,11,21,1211,111221, \ldots$$

Comment: A couple of related topics on MSE:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653049/is-the-look-and-say-sequence-a-proper-maths-problem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620905/on-the-look-and-say-sequence-and-conways-constant

Comment: [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next number is 312211. Hint read the sequence out loud!;)

Answer (score 7):

See the [Look-and-Say Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

Answer (score 3):

$312211$. And since we need $30$ characters...