# Find the next number

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I am given a sequence

$$1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221, \cdots$$

what is the next number?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: Looks as sequence $A005150$ at OEIS.

Comment: @IttayWeiss you beat me by 21s.. :-)

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715981/what-is-the-next-number/715997#715997) as well

Comment: This is an ill-defined question. The next number could be anything.

Comment: @SDiv Yes, there is no "correct" answer. I posted it out of curiosity to find interesting pattern

Comment: @ LiuGang. Indeed, I regret my comment following reading of joriki's post here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/924/guess-the-next-number-guess-the-relation-etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Wikipedia article [Look-and-say sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) and say ...