# Examples of famous constants that turned out to be rational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, constants

I was just reading through some random articles on the proofs (or lackthere of) of some famous constants being irrational or transcendental. (Such as $ \pi, e$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant etc.)

Obviously $\pi$ and $e$ are known to be transcendental but the Euler-Mascheroni hasn't even been proven to be irrational although most suspect it is transcendental from what I've read.

So what I'm wondering about is if anyone is familiar with examples of any constants in science that were thought to irrational/transcendental  but were later proven to be rational.

I'm already aware of Legendres Constant (that is the constant in the asympyotic expression of the prime counting function) was proven to be exactly $1$. So I'm curious if there are other examples of a similar situation to Legendre.

Comment: A somewhat similar example: Conway's constant for the look-and-say sequence is an algebraic number.

Comment: There's an old popular thread about this on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32967/have-any-long-suspected-irrational-numbers-turned-out-to-be-rational

Comment: @colt_browning Yes, and of degree-$71$ with small coefficients. I wonder if, a priori, they knew it was algebraic?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII On one hand, nobody investigated the look-and-say sequence in detail before Conway, except maybe with numerical experiments (which could suggest the existence of the constant), so nobody knew that. On the other hand, the number being algebraic is a somewhat natural corollary of his idea of elements. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620905/on-the-look-and-say-sequence-and-conways-constant (oops, this is your own question... Still, the answers kind of explain where does the algebraicity come from.)

Answer (score 3):

When Onsager found the critical exponents for the 2D Ising model, they turned out to be rational numbers.

Comment: Interesting! Are the critical exponents known to be rational for even dimensions? Because from a quick search I noticed the 4D Ising model has rational critical exponents.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.